# cq5saver configuration for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, aem

The author of cq5saver for Sublime 3 talks about the possibility of configuring the plugin to use a different username and password than 'admin' 'admin' but does not explain how.
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CQ5Saver
Does anyone know how to change the configuration of this plugin? If so, could you provide an example?

Comment: how did you make it work for you? I installde it and it does not work or log anything.

Comment: Do you have AEM installed and an author instance running? That's a prerequisite to getting this to work.

Comment: Yes, I do. But I don’t get any feedback that it’s working.